# Getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: datepart for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, exception, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am newbie to jenkins pipeline scripting and i am just trying to concatenate date to string getting below No Such Property exception. Dont know where am doing wrong. Could some one please help me to resolve this

```
def generateRandomText(){

    def temp = ""
    try{
         Date date = new Date()                
         String datePart = date.format("ddHHmmssSSS")
         temp = "abcde" + datepart
         echo "printing ... $temp"      
         return temp
    }
    catch(theError){
        echo "Error getting while generating random text: {$theError}"
    }
    return temp

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`MissingPropertyException`** means the variable wasn't declared.

There were some errors in your code:

1. You used `echo`, which doesn't exist in Groovy. Use one of the `print` functions instead. On the code below I used `println`
2. **The `datePart` variable was mispelled**

Here's your code fixed:

```
def generateRandomText(){
    def temp = ""
    try{
        Date date = new Date()                
        String datePart = date.format("ddHHmmssSSS")
        temp = "abcde" + datePart
        println "printing ... $temp"      
        return temp
    }
    catch(theError){
        println "Error getting while generating random text: {$theError}"
    }
    return temp
}

generateRandomText()
```

Output on [groovyConsole](http://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html):

```
printing ... abcde21195603124
Result: abcde21195603124
```

See [Groovy's documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html).